# centering <ul> <li> horizontal drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, megamenu, horizontallist

I've been unable to center this horizontal list drop down menu. Will I have to rework all the css because i'm using a float left?

Here is all the code pertaining to the position of the list. 
or alternatively click here to view it live

```
.megamenu {
margin:auto;
position:absolute;
margin:0;
width:100%;
font-size:1.182em;
list-style:none;
padding:0px;
line-height:38px;
font-weight: bold;
display:block;
list-style:none;
border-right: none;
top: -1px;
list-style-type:none;
list-style-position:inside;




.megamenu > li {

    display:inline;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
    padding: 0px 0 0px 30px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out; 
    border-right: none;
    transition: background-color 0.4s ease-out;

}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you want the menu itself to be centered on the page, or the black area that appears on hover to be centered on the page, or both?

Comment: I would like both to be centered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to do this - you'll need to give it a width, though, instead of 100%. Is that ok?

Then with a width in place, you can use `display:inline` on the ul, and `text-align:center` on the parent div, or maybe use `margin:auto`.

If this doesn't help, let me know, I will make a fiddle for you :)

Comment: Initially this is what i had tried to do, however it didn't yield any results! 
Im testing Roddy's method at the moment, however making a fiddle for me would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had many problems with this but I finally found a solution one day. It was the use of a table and css auto margins. Here is my trick. Just change the width in the center td and add the navigation.

```
<table>
<td style="margin:0 auto;">
</td>
<td width="800"> <----Change this to the width of your nav bar.

PUT THE NAVIGATION HERE

</td>
<td style="margin:0 auto;">
</td>
</table>
```

Comment: let me try to do it with your navigation brb

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you shouldn't be nesting block level elements inside inline elements. That being said, I've created [this JSFiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/BAsS4/) by simplifying your HTML and replacing the `<div>` that holds the "Content" with a sub un-ordered list instead. (In theory, this sublist, which has just one `<li>`, should be able to then hold the `<div>` with the content if you so desire.)

The HTML is thus:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Home
        <ul>
            <li>Content</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>One day
        <ul>
            <li>Content</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>I wish to
        <ul>
            <li>Content</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Be in the
        <ul>
            <li>Content</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Centre of this page
        <ul>
            <li>Content</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

And the CSS was set like so:

```
#menu {
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
}

#menu li {
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 5px 15px;
}

#menu li ul {
    display: none;
}

#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px; /* height of menu */
    left: 25px;
    right: 25px;
}
```

In the JSFiddle I've added some colors to make it obvious what element is where. I've also stripped out the animation CSS that you had in your live example as well, but that should be simple to slip back in.

This method relies on giving the menu an absolute height -- in this example `30px` -- and then absolutely positioning the "content" `<div>` that appears on hover below it with `top: 30px` (or whatever the menu height happens to be).

Comment: I'll give this method a go, however from research i think putting it in a list might just be what I have to do. Thanks for taking the time and I'll keep you updated and let you know If it does work after all :)

Comment: I've spent a few hours trying to re attach the drop down to the page, with no success.

Comment: @uneducatedguy -- What's the problem? It seems [pretty straightforward](http://jsfiddle.net/BAsS4/4/). Just stick the rest of the content underneath the menu.